# What are different storages available/Setting>available in IOS?

Tags: ios, storage

I used the below method, so I got the available storage.. around 198MB.

However, I see the different value when i check phone, Setting > General > About > Available 0 Byte.

Why there are different ?

{
...

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];  

if (dictionary) {  
    NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];  
    NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
    totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes floatValue];
    totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes floatValue];
    NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %f MiB with %f MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024.0f)/1024.0f), ((totalFreeSpace/1024.0f)/1024.0f));
    }
```

...

}

hmm.. i googled.. 2 days.. but i don't know exactly .. Thats why.. 
(Iphone 200MB / IPod 160MB .. there are different storage)

Comment: 198MB is the `totalSpace` or `totalFreeSpace` ? what about the values of `Iphone 200MB / IPod 160MB` ?

Comment: it's totalFreeSpace.   and Iphone 200MB. Ipod 160MB mean differences in memory (ex) Setting>Available> 0 Byte but the totlaFreeSpace is 200MB.

Comment: just curious, how can you use up all the free spaces in your phone ?

Comment: Insert many movies.. and take photos then recording video for Testing.  You can see 0 Byte in Settings. hmm.. If you know that's why, let me know please.. :)

Comment: you should cast the `NSFileSystemFreeSize` as `unsigned long long value` instead of `float value`. `unsigned long long freeSize = [(NSNumber*)[dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] unsignedLongLongValue];`

Comment: yes.. i tried.  but it didn't .. I don't know why .. hm...